# How do you reference "this" in an Angular2 component template?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 component:

```
class A {
  filter(..)
}
```

In the template for A, I have

```
<.. list | pipe:filter ..>
```

Inside of pipe I call filter, the problem is I do not have a reference to "this", since JS is dynamically scoped I can't access the instance variables of A inside of filter when I call it. Is there a way to get a "this" reference?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need `this`. You should be able to call `filter()` and it should get interpolated without the need for `this`. But you need to put it in `{{ }}` i.e.

```
{{list | pipe:filter()}}
```

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4kZYqk265Vslu7UdMoOa?p=preview)

Comment: No I understand this part. The filter resolves fine, but when I call filter from within pipe, the "this" resolves to window. I need it to resolve to the component.

Comment: You're going to need to show a little more code. There's no `this` in your example. Where are you using `this`? Are you trying to use it in the template?

Comment: ok, so what I did was add a variable to the component
class Component {
  constructor() { this.self = this; }
}

and I reference self from the template. I was wondering if there is a built in variable that automatically reference "this" that's accessible from the template.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to reference "this" in the pipe, you may have to set a property of your component to "this"

```
export class Component() {
    that = this;
}
```

and then pass "that" as a parameter in your filter.